# How to get a public calendar events with deno

Tags: google-api-client, deno

I want to get the events of a public calendar (only read) via google API for Deno:

https://doc.deno.land/https://googleapis.deno.dev/v1/calendar:v3.ts

I'm struggling finding an example to get the events of a calendar publicly shared (only read) which I have the `id`.

I'm not sure if I'm ok with an API key, a service account, and not sure how to create an instance with both of them